# Find corresponding OSM ways to a set of coordinates

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api, srtm, open-source-routing-machine

I'm currently building a routing application that is based on the Open Source Routing Machine (OSRM), which uses OSM data. For the routes i am trying to generate elevation profiles using SRTM data.

So far OSRM returns me a route as a list of coordinates that i then feed into an API to get the corresponding elevations. However, I would like to detect sections in a route that consist of tunnels and fix the corresponding elevations.
The information to whether a road is a tunnel, is stored in the corresponding OSM 'way' (see tag 'tunnel').

Now to my question: How could I efficiently find the coordinates in my list that belong to tunnel-sections? My first thought would be some kind of map matching of these coordinates to OSM ways with the Overpass API, which are then checked for the 'tunnel' tag. And then convert the way back to the corresponding coordinates. However, this seems overly complicated and error-prone. Anyone got an idea how to efficiently solve this problem?